# Setting container width automatically in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, containers

I am loading data from Api. So I need to set it inside a container. So I can't set a fixed width. The width should change automatically or expand according to the length of data. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please share UI snap & code of what you want you want to achieve & what you've done so far

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your container with the Expanded widget.

Comment: nah bro. That ain't working. I am using listview inside the container to load data.

Comment: in that case, try setting shrinkWrap:true inyour listview builder

Answer (score 0):

Just one add to Mansoor's answer Malik you can assign a minWidth in constraints. To make the container appear even if there is no text inside it